# APR memory not freed after pool destroy

Tags: c, apr

```
apr_pool_t *pool;
char *a;
char *b;

apr_pool_create(&pool, NULL);
a = (char *) apr_palloc(pool, 10);

strcpy(a, "hello");
printf("a is %s\n", a);

apr_pool_destroy(pool);
apr_terminate();
b = (char *) apr_palloc(pool, 10);

strcpy(b, "world");
printf("b is %s\n", b);
```

I'm new to libapr, from the document it said

> Destroy the pool. This takes similar action as apr_pool_clear() and then frees all the memory.

but actually it's not, and I can still use `apr_palloc` to alloc memory from a destroyed pool? so my question is how can I actually free the memory and how can I actually destroy the pool object

Comment: This is [probably] UB. Just by luck, the 2nd `apr_palloc` works, probably because you haven't done anything in between that [indirectly] does a `malloc`. But, you shouldn't rely on this [`apr_palloc` probably doesn't _check_ (for speed) and just assumes it's passed a _valid/active_ pointer].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking Undefined Behavior in at least two places.
I compiled on my linux (Mint a derived of Ubuntu), gcc 7.4. Your program crashes at the first `apr_pool_create` because you did not invoke the appropriate initialization functions (e.g. `apr_initialize`), see https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.6/group__apr__library.html .
Here is the Valgrind trace:

```
==7158== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7158==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x30
==7158==    at 0x4E595F0: apr_pool_create_ex (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.so.0.6.3)
==7158==    by 0x1088EB: main (in /home/user/apr/test)
=
```

Once that issue is fixed, you get the following program (note: I do not know whether `apr_initialize` or `apr_app_initialize` is appropriate for your use case).

```
    apr_pool_t *pool;
    char *a;
    char *b;

    apr_initialize(); // You need this or apr_app_initialize

    apr_pool_create(&pool, NULL);
    a = (char *) apr_palloc(pool, 10);

    strcpy(a, "hello");
    printf("a is %s\n", a);

    apr_pool_destroy(pool);
    apr_terminate();

    b = (char *) apr_palloc(pool, 10);

    strcpy(b, "world");
    printf("b is %s\n", b);
```

The above code crashes in the second `apr_palloc` with the following Valgrind trace because you are accessing memory that was freed most likely as a consequence of `apr_pool_destroy`

```
a is hello
==7196== Invalid read of size 8
==7196==    at 0x4E58A62: apr_palloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.so.0.6.3)
==7196==    by 0x1089AF: main (in /home/user/apr/test)
==7196==  Address 0x402d080 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7196==
```

Removing the last lines

```
    b = (char *) apr_palloc(pool, 10);

    strcpy(b, "world");
    printf("b is %s\n", b);
```

allow the program to terminate correctly and Valgrind shows no errors.

So it looks like `apr_pool_destroy` is working correctly, you were simply accessing memory you were not supposed to have access to and you did not experience a crash: Undefined Behavior is sneaky, your program can run for years without showing any problem, and then, one day it crashes.

For completeness, I compiled with the following command (the code was in test.c):

```
gcc -Wall test.c $(apr-1-config --cflags --cppflags --includes --link-ld) -o test
```

I suggest that you should use tools like Valgrind (http://www.valgrind.org/) to detect these kind of issues.

User Eliyahu Machluf (thanks) makes the point that APR provides facilities to debug memory allocation, from http://download.vikis.lt/manual/developer/debugging.html

> Allocation Debugging
>
> ALLOC_DEBUG
>
> Debugging support: Define this to enable code which helps detect re-use of
> free()d memory and other such nonsense.
> The theory is simple. The FILL_BYTE (0xa5) is written over
> all malloc'd memory as we receive it, **and is written over everything
> that we free up during a clear_pool**. We check that blocks on the free
> list always have the FILL_BYTE in them, and we check during palloc()
> that the bytes still have FILL_BYTE in them. If you ever see garbage
> URLs or whatnot containing lots of 0xa5s then you know something used
> data that's been freed or uninitialized.

Comment: thanks, I test the code on mac, and I will test it on linux, thanks for your suggestion to use valgrind

Comment: Great, let me know how it goes. I am considering this library for a project.

Comment: BTW, apr at debug version has an option to fill all allocated memory with 0xa5 byte when pool is destroyed. this is useful to actively cause such freed memory have garbage instead of sometimes valid data, and sometimes corrupted data.
See http://download.vikis.lt/manual/developer/debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out previously, apr_initialize is a pre-requisite to *using* the pools. But the opposite of initialising the required data structures before use is tearing them down at the other end. That's what apr_terminate does. It makes no sense to try to use the library for memory allocation after you've taken away the stuff that it relies on.

If you run your program under valgrind as is (with the addition of the initialize) and then compare it to a second version where the apr_terminate is moved to just before the end of your code you should see a clear difference.